# Quotations around the letter t: csquotes

Tags: punctuation, csquotes

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%make " quotation marks 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
\texttt{read.table(file, sep = "t")}
\end{document}
```

The desired output should be obvious from the code above. The output from this is the following:

[image]

Comment: The `tt` font has a backslash where the standard text font has the opening double quote, so that effect is to be expected.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the information. Does the `tt` font have an opening quote? Or would I have to use ``t'' (two single quotes at the end)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character `"` is made active, to expand to a double opening or closing quote (context depending). However, the typewriter font in OT1 encoding has a backslash where the text fonts have the double opening quote.

Solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%make " quotation marks
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`"
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \DeclareTextFontCommand{\texttt}{\ttfamily\def~{"}}%
}

\begin{document}
\texttt{read.table(file, sep = "t")}
\end{document}
```

This won't work if you nest quoted text in normal font inside `\texttt`. It won't work also in the scope of `\ttfamily`, but it could be arranged for.

[image]